# WiX project to allow revision based upgrades and side-by-side (multi instance support) installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am a great fan of continuous integration, deployment and delivery. I believe that revision based upgrades is way to go here but it seems like using WIX based installers makes it really hard to support this feature. I am currently trying to change installer of our product so that it can be installed side-by-side (multi instance support) and allow revision based upgrades. In my case I want to allow installation of 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1 version of product side by side and also support upgrade any of installation like just allowing upgrading from 1.0.0.1 to 1.0.0.2 without changing 1.0.0.0 version of product.

So in given scenario,

1. When installing 1.0.0.1 on top of 1.0.0.0, then 1.0.0.0 needs to be upgraded.
2. When installing 1.0.0.1 as new instances, then both 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1 needs to be co-exist on same box (Installation will use different location). It should installed like a new one and display in Add/Remove program twice.
3. In future 1.0.0.2 should be able to upgrade any one existing instance (1.0.0.0 or 1.0.0.1) without changing other instances.
4. Installing 1.0.0.1 on 1.0.0.1 should perform usual repair.
5. Installer should prevent downgrade.

I tried Wix MajorUpgrade element but it didn't work the way i wanted.  Here is complete result of my experiment.

**1. Install 1.0.0.0 then upgrade to 1.0.0.1. It works well (as expected)**

**2. Install 1.0.0.1 as new instance then both 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1 co-exist on same box (Works).**

**3. Install 1.0.0.2 as upgrade to 1.0.0.0 (not 1.0.0.1). Here is problem. It uninstalls everything (both 1.0.0.0 and 1.0.0.1) and didn't installed 1.0.0.2 properly.**

Last result was really weird and i am not sure how to make that work where installation should upgraded target version only without uninstalling all instances ? Any help or guidance will be really appreciated.

```
<Product Id="*"
           Name="$(var.ProductName)"
             Language="1033"
             Version="$(var.Version)"
             Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)"
           UpgradeCode="MY-UPGRADE-CODE">


<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to stop using the MajorUpgrade element and build version specific upgrades. MajorUpgrade is basically a short and sweet way to get every prior version upgraded. Instead, you need to build specific WiX Upgrade elements that target the specific version range you want to upgrade. Your 1.0.0.2 would have an Upgrade element that targets only version 1.0.0.0 for the upgrade.

Can't say much about the failed upgrade without more detail as to what you mean about not installed properly. I note that you have your upgrade scheduled after InstallInitialize, and that means that you'll need to increment file versions to replace files and follow component rules if you're installing the same resources to the same locations. Maybe that's where the issue is.